# How to get the volume data of mp3 audio bytes every second? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, mp3

I have and audio bytes `Uint8List` of mp3 file and I want to normalise the audio

My first thought comes on how to get the volume length at every second before I get to normalise it.

Any thought provided is highly appreciated.

Comment: _normalising_ the audio and dynamically increasing the gain would require different approaches. It might be worthwhile elaborating on your overall goal here. As always, a basic, bare bones script with reading audio and a space display would go down wonderfully and avoid any heavy lifting

Comment: the goal is to keep all audio songs have the same volume level.

Comment: Lovely. That sort of falls under the umbrella of audio mastering. With _loudness_ you not only have to take into account peaks but also dynamic range. Normalising will bring the peak of each audio track to a uniform value, but some songs may have a larger dynamic range than others. In that instance, really some kind of [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5baudio%5dcompressor) will be required. Getting this to sound nice in an automated way is definitely non-trivial, but something passible should be achievable.

Comment: That is to say [**dynamic range compression**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-range-compression) not file size compression.

Comment: I also want to detect the volume at the end of each song so I can make crossfade in playlist transition. any code I can refer to? I am new with audio programming

Comment: For crossfading there needs to be an overlap between when one track ends and another starts. A linear ramp can then applied. The problem here is that the goal posts have just moved, which is not really in the spirit of SO. I’d first focus on solving some individual problems then look to stitching them together . For instance, can you change the volume of an audio file? If no, then _that_ should be your first _self-contained_ question, nothing else. Also, I’d implement a basic version of the program then think hard if these are problems you _need_ to solve.

Comment: One blind-spot of flutter is audio processing. If you’re interesting in audio programming it’s a nice challenge. If you’re looking for quick results, then maybe check out some flutter packages https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=Audio

Comment: Probably just-audio has the most active community https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/just-audio?sort=votes

Comment: Thanks @fdcpp. Yes I am interested in audio programming, anywhere I can refer to for doing audio normalization?

Comment: @ffcpp, Do you know ffmpeg commands? is there a command that normalises mp3 file?